# Помогите найти определение к "атмосфере", употреблённой не в прямом своём значении

Tags: выбор-слов

> Монти. Первый район города Рима обозначается на картах соответствующей
>   римской цифрой, а название его переводится с итальянского как «горы»,
>   хотя **по атмосфере это скорее можно назвать очаровательной долиной**.

Или чем заменить атмосферу; или и так всё понятно, читатель не споткнётся (как я)?

Comment: Может "по климату"? Если это имелось в виду. А если нет, то выглядит очень корявой метафорой (или я не способен её понять).

Comment: А термин "атмосферное кино" Вам понятен? Здесь примерно о том же.

Comment: Термин "атмосферное кино" мне понятен. А здесь мне не хватает одних коннотаций, при этом другие сказываются сильнее. Но это всё имхо — не исключаю, что это мои проблемы, а не автора. Главное, чтоб это не было проблемой для целевой аудитории книги.

Comment: Так я и прошу ***поясняющее*** определение к атмосфере!

Comment: Вариант: ...хотя по царящей там атмосфере это (может лучше - его?) скорее можно назвать очаровательной долиной.

Comment: Автор будет думать. Спасибо за варианты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом контексте, как мне кажется, **определениями** к "атмосфере" могут быть:
романтическая, созерцательная, пейзажная, панорамная, ландшафтная.

А если **заменять** "атмосферу", то, возможно, подойдет:
очертание, восприятие, ощущение.

Или даже симбиоз: панорамное ощущение, пейзажное восприятие, романтические очертания...

Comment: Мне кажется, по ощущению(ям) — наиболее соответствующий синоним.